# Google Analytics in C#

Tags: c#, google-analytics

i want to use c# code in place of javascript code for google analytics

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
```

C#

```
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
        query.Add("utmwv", "4.9");
        query.Add("utmhn", "host name"); 
        query.Add("utmcs", "UTF-8");
        query.Add("utmul", "en-us");
        query.Add("utmdt", "google analysis... c#"); 
        query.Add("utmac", "UA-xxxxxx-x");
        string m = "http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(m);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Headers.Add("GData-Version", "2");
   var uri = new UriBuilder("http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?");
        uri.Query = query.ToString();


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri.ToString());
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Headers.Add("GData-Version", "2");
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(query.ToString());
        Stream input = request.GetRequestStream();
        input.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        input.Close();
        HttpWebResponse nsResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream streamResponse = nsResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
```

with above code i am making a web request but no avail. am i missing something, or any better approach for it ?

Comment: What's the error /  HTTP return code you get? (Assuming you actually look at the Response)

Comment: i recieve this response and no traffic on google analysis."GIF89a\0\0��\0���\0\0\0,\0\0\0\0\0\0\0D\0;"

Comment: @Hidsman this return value is "GIF89a\0\0��\0���\0\0\0,\0\0\0\0\0\0\0D\0;"  ok. because it return gif image as response. :)

Comment: i sorted out the problem... check this->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851868/how-to-send-request-to-google-analytics-in-non-web-based-app

Answer (score -1):

It should be a `GET` request instead of a `POST`. Not sure if that makes a difference but you've certainly missed out quite a few parameters in the example above. You should use something like Firebug or Live HTTP Headers to see what's being sent to Google Analytics and mimic that.

I also can't see the query being added to the request in your code but maybe you didn't post that bit here.

Comment: i did tried with both post and get. no error. in resposne i get "GIF89a\0\0��\0���\0\0\0,\0\0\0\0\0\0\0D\0;" but next day no traffic on googla analysis.

Comment: This didn't help me. =(