# How to send request to Google Analytics in non web based app

Tags: c#, winforms, google-analytics

i want to send request to Google analytics in non web based application(Windows based application) ?
i tried following method.

```
public string  trackingId = "UA-XXXXXXXX-2";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string shopname = "ShopTestng";
    string pagename="Testing_MyApp";
    callAnalyticsmethod2(pagename, shopname);
}

private void callAnalyticsmethod2(string pageName, string shopname)
{
    // create hash code base on pc name 7 user name    
    string visitorId = GetUniqueUserId(); 
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageName))
        pageName = visitorId;

    string utmGifLocation = "http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif";

    string GifUrl = "utmwv=4.9" +
        "&utmn=" + GetRandomNumber() +
        "&utmp=" + pageName +
        "&utmac=" + trackingId +
        "&utmcc=__utma%3D999.999.999.999.999.1%3B" +
        "&utmvid=" + visitorId;// + "?" +

    string shop = shopname.Replace(" ", "_");
    string addipara = GifUrl+"&utmr=http://" + shop;

    byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(addipara);

    string request = utmGifLocation;

    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(request);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webRequest.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
    Stream newStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    // Send the data.
    newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
    newStream.Close();
    WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
    MessageBox.Show((((HttpWebResponse)webResponse).StatusDescription));

    newStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(newStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer);

    reader.Close();
    newStream.Close();
    webResponse.Close();
}
```

according to the above code sample

```
MessageBox.Show((((HttpWebResponse)webResponse).StatusDescription));
```

line display as "OK". but when i check Google analytics, visit count doesn't increase. what is the reason for this?
is there something i missing or any other way to send request to analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found similar answer from SOF ([Cause Google Analytics log from non-web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846460/cause-google-analytics-log-from-non-web-application-eg-via-webclient)  and editted it according to my scenario.

```
    private void analyticsmethod4(string trackingId, string pagename)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        long timestampFirstRun, timestampLastRun, timestampCurrentRun, numberOfRuns;

        // Get the first run time
        timestampFirstRun = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        timestampLastRun = DateTime.Now.Ticks-5;
        timestampCurrentRun = 45;
        numberOfRuns = 2;

        // Some values we need
        string domainHash = "123456789"; // This can be calcualted for your domain online
        int uniqueVisitorId = rnd.Next(100000000, 999999999); // Random
        string source = "Shop";
        string medium = "medium123";
        string sessionNumber = "1";
        string campaignNumber = "1";
        string culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
        string screenRes = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width + "x" + Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;


        string statsRequest = "http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif" +
            "?utmwv=4.6.5" +
            "&utmn=" + rnd.Next(100000000, 999999999) +
        //  "&utmhn=hostname.mydomain.com" +
            "&utmcs=-" +
            "&utmsr=" + screenRes +
            "&utmsc=-" +
            "&utmul=" + culture +
            "&utmje=-" +
            "&utmfl=-" +
            "&utmdt=" + pagename +
            "&utmhid=1943799692" +
            "&utmr=0" +
            "&utmp=" + pagename +
            "&utmac=" +trackingId+ // Account number
            "&utmcc=" +
                "__utma%3D" + domainHash + "." + uniqueVisitorId + "." + timestampFirstRun + "." + timestampLastRun + "." + timestampCurrentRun + "." + numberOfRuns +
                "%3B%2B__utmz%3D" + domainHash + "." + timestampCurrentRun + "." + sessionNumber + "." + campaignNumber + ".utmcsr%3D" + source + "%7Cutmccn%3D(" + medium + ")%7Cutmcmd%3D" + medium + "%7Cutmcct%3D%2Fd31AaOM%3B";


        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadData(statsRequest);
            //Stream data = client.OpenRead(statsRequest);
            //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
            //string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
```

**I found good Articles about -**

[Google Analytics for Desktop Application](http://tilr.blogspot.com/2012/10/google-analytics-use-google-analytics.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you turn off the filter that causes analytics not to log your own requests.**

```
// Send a hit to Google Analytics
Random rnd = new Random();
int cookie = rnd.Next(10000000, 99999999);
string statsRequest = "http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif" +
    "?utmwv=4.3" +
    "&utmn=" + rnd.Next(10000) + // Used only to stop browser caching
    "&utmhn=myhost.com" + // Hostname
    //"&utmhid=<random#>" +
    "&utmr=-" + // Referer
    "&utmp=/app/v0.4/DEBUG/Test" + // Requested page
    "&utmac=UA-654321-0" + // Google Analytics ID
    "&utmcc=__utma%3D" + cookie + "3B%2B__utmz%3D" + cookie + "%3B";

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadData(statsRequest);
}
```

Comment: how to turn off those filters?